# How to manage and save nested arrays to django models

Tags: django, django-models

I'm receiving the data from the frontend app in the form of Arrays, or say List of objects.
I want to create and save the data using Django models and views.
I'm a little confused about how can make a structure of tables to save this type of data
That's how would be I receiving data:

```
[
  { question: 'Screen Works Properly', parentId: 1, child: [] },
  {
    question: 'Theres issue  of Hardware',
    parentId: 2,
    child: [
      { id: 15, sub_question: 'Broken Speakers' },
      { id: 18, sub_question: 'Battery Damaged' }
    ]
  }
]
```

There could an unlimited number of objects in the list and every object has a child array which can have an unlimited number of objects as well.

I can see there I can make a model Data and then can link the objects with ForeignKey, But how will I manage the child Array/list in the object. Can anybody give me an idea of how can I create models to save this type of data?

That's my try :

```
class Data(models.Model):
    order = models.OneToOneField(
        PickupOrder, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id


class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(
        Data, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id


class Child(models.Model):
    child = models.OneToOneField(
        Question, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id


class SubQuestion(models.Model):
    sub_question = models.ForeignKey(
        Child, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

**Do u think that is the proper way to manage it? Or there can be some flaws or any better way to approach this.**